# Get the selected items from an array of drop-down lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have many drop-down lists, which are created dynamically? Му model:

```
public class Block
{
    public string SelectedField { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
      ......
      public List<Block> Blocks { get; set; }

      public List<SelectListItem> Fields { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>()
      {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "text1"},
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "text2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "text3" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "text4"},
            new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "text5" }
       };
}
```

how i can get selected items from view?

```
@model FormEditor.Models.Form
.......
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Blocks.Count; i++)
  {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Blocks[i].SelectedField, new SelectList(Model.Fields,"Value","Text"), new { @class= "custom-select" })
```

this code returns null

Comment: It is not clear from your question, which part of the code returns null for you?

Comment: @Ayrat M has my answer worked for you?

Comment: @TanvirArjel no, I will try using ajax

Comment: Why ajax, this should solve your problem greatly if you can use them properly.

Comment: @Demarsch  SelectedField=null   after post request

Comment: @TanvirArjel I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you give remote access with team viewer please?

Comment: @TanvirArjel can I give you a link to GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

First update your `Block` class as follows:

```
public class Block
{
    public List<string> SelectedField { get; set; }
}
```

And then your `@Html.DropDownListFor` as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Blocks[i].SelectedField, Model.Fields,"Select Item" new { @class= "custom-select" })
```